# Getting uTorrent's "Status" column to respect its row's background

Tags: gui, utorrent

uTorrent 3.1.3 (and possibly earlier) has an "alternate list background color" option that is useful and lovely, but the "status" column does not display its row's background, instead displaying its own color. It throws me off completely. Is there any way to get that column to respect its row's background?

[image: Example of problem]

Comment: Which version of utorrent you are using?

Comment: @avirk 3.1.3. Do you know a version that doesn't exhibit this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such option. However, you could try to submit your proposal to the µTorrent Development team.

They run a nice website to do so: http://www.utorrent.com/community/ideabank

Comment: Sounds like that's that. Shame. I've made a suggestion on their forums. Thanks.